# web.config issues when migrating old .net 4.6.1 web api to .net 6

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0

We have a legacy web api project developed years ago, it is supposed to be consumed by other internal projects (so not something to be exposed by users over Internet).

The prject was developed in .net 4.6.1 and I am looking at moving it to .net 6. By reading the code and web.config, I got confused with these:

1. Is it acceptable or best practice to keep on using web.config in .net 6 for these settings or it is better to do in other places? (seems I can't type web.config in stackoverflow and have to make a screenshot)

[image]

2. In our web.config, we have this: `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />`

For this web api, we just send some response back and I can't think a place that we use cookie. For authentication, as this web api is consumed by other internal products, we just authenticate the bear token each request sent with the identity server. So is this line really needed? I can't find an equivalent line in .net 6's web.config

Comment: The .NET Core universe typically uses an `appSettings.json` file for its settings - but IIS-related settings will still have to be in a  `web.config` file - so in the end, you'll probably have both - one for your apps settings, one for IIS-related settings

Answer (score 0):

1. There are different ways on specifying application settings in .NET 6, depending on what kind of setting it is and how you want to structure your project. As Marc says the most common application configuration file for .NET Core is that I have seen is: `appSettings.json`.
   You might want to configure some settings directly in your `Program.cs` and other settings (especially settings that need to be transformed between environments) could be in a transformable settings file like `appSettings.json` or `lauchSettings.json`. Read more about configuration in .NET 6 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#environment-variables).
   To conclude I would say that it is not best practice to keep the `web.config` but rather to extract the configuration to the place you see fit. If you don't host you app on a server that needs `web.config` to run then remove it.
2. This is a bit harder to answer. If you don't think you need this setting then you can try to omit it when you migrate your application to .NET 6. If you have multiple environments you should test your application (the .NET 6 version) in a non production environment and then you will get your answer if you need to configure that setting or not in the migrated application.

I wish you good luck in your migration journey! :)